# Provide the "script" argument in elasticsearch-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am trying to replicate the following `curl` commando in `elasticsearch-py`:

```bash
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/my-exact-knn-index/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "filter" : {
            "range" : {
              "my-price" : {
                "gte": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "\n          double value = dotProduct(params.query_vector, 'my-product-vector');\n          return sigmoid(1, Math.E, -value); \n        ",
        "params": {
          "query_vector": [-0.5, 90.0, -10, 14.8, -156.0]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I am having trouble understanding how to provide the "script" part to the `index.search()` call. I tried providing it in the `query` parameter, and in the `body` parameter (which is deprecated now), but it gives me a `BadRequestError`:

```py
query_body = {
    "script_score": {
      "script": {
        "source": "\n          double value = dotProduct(params.query_vector, '\''my-product-vector'\'');\n          return sigmoid(1, Math.E, -value); \n        ",
        "params": {
          "query_vector": [-0.5, 90.0, -10, 14.8, -156.0]
        }
      }
    }
  }


search_results = client.search(index="my-exact-knn-index", query=query_body)

>>> BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Required [query]')
```

Any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you simply need a `query` section:

```
query_body = {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {                   <----- add this
          ....
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "\n          double value = dotProduct(params.query_vector, '\''my-product-vector'\'');\n          return sigmoid(1, Math.E, -value); \n        ",
        "params": {
          "query_vector": [-0.5, 90.0, -10, 14.8, -156.0]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, when I add that, I get another 400: `BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'unknown query [query]')`.

Comment: The `query` section had to come after the `script_score`. But thank you, I got it to work after looking at the body closer!

Comment: There's one outside and one inside, but indeed you are missing the inner one.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing the following:

```py
query_body = {
    "script_score": {
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "filter" : {
            "range" : {
              "my-price" : {
                "gte": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "\n          double value = dotProduct(params.query_vector, 'my-product-vector');\n          return sigmoid(1, Math.E, -value); \n        ",
        "params": {
          "query_vector": [-0.5, 90.0, -10, 14.8, -156.0]
        }
      }
    }
}

search_results = client.search(index="my-exact-knn-index", query=query_body)
```

So the `query` had to come after the `script_score`.